# What is the "leakage current" between signal and shield?

Tags: operational-amplifier, shielding

Consider a coaxial cable with shield not connected to anything. My textbook seems to suggest that there will be leakage current between the "signal" and the "shield".

I have two questions:

1) When the s*hield isn't connected to anything*, how can any current be there and where will the current flow to?

2) How does connecting the shield to common mode voltage *reduce both leakage current and capacitance*?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A wire inside a metal shield is a capacitor!

Comment: Ok I see how two metals at distance form a capacitor. Pardon if I'm dumb but how is it possible to charge/discharge the capacitor when one terminal is not connected to anything?

Comment: Whereabouts in the quoted text does it imply the shield is unconnected when you say this *Consider a coaxial cable with shield not connected to anything. My textbook seems to suggest that there will be leakage current between the "signal" and the "shield".*

Comment: @Andyaka Oh Looks I just assumed that.because the author was proposing to connect the shield to common mode potential. Do you mean they must be "grounding" the shield before? If so, I guess it makes sense. The leakage current was flowing to the ground through the capacitor. I still don't get how putting common mode potential on shield reduces the capacitance though...

Comment: Leakage current might reduce because the voltage difference between signal and shield was reduced. But how can capacitance be changed with voltage? Isn't capacitance purely a geometric property?

Comment: I don’t think shield drivers bring much to the party. What text book is it?

Comment: @Andyaka Electronics principles by Malvino. [Here](https://www.amazon.com/Electronic-Principles-Albert-Paul-Malvino/dp/0073373885) is amazon link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1) When the shield isn't connected to anything, how can any current be there and where will the current flow to?*

The shield is ordinarily connected to ground or some other low-impedance path to ground. If it wasn't, it wouldn't be that useful in stopping noise. With such a connection, the (grounded) shield forms a capacitor between itself and the leads inside, biased at the common-mode voltage.

Because no insulator is perfect, there is a small leakage current as well, modeled as a resistance to ground. The greater the voltage difference between shield and leads, the greater the leakage.

*2) How does connecting the shield to common mode voltage reduce both leakage current and capacitance?*

Driving the shield to the common-mode voltage reduces the DC bias between the shield and the signal lines. With a smaller (or practically no) bias, there is no DC leakage. It also cancels out the common-mode AC voltage so it doesn't influence the signal pair either.

Some relevant info:

- biometrics: https://www.biosemi.com/publications/pdf/Interference_reduction.pdf
- instrumentation: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/41727248AN_347.pdf

Comment: Ah pulling the shield to common mode potential reduces the voltage between "signal" and "shield". Consequently, less leakage current XD You're so awesome! Thank you so much:)

Comment: If I may ask one quick q:  when you/textbook say "grounding the shield" it is the *circuit* ground and not the earth right?

Comment: Yes, the system (circuit) ground.